# mdframed box containing text captioned tables and figures

Tags: floats, mdframed

I would like to create a framed boxes containing arbitrary text, captioned tables and captioned figures. But `mdframed` does not allow floats inside. How does one achieve this? Something like this does not work because you cannot insert a float inside `mdframed`:

```
\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[4-6]
\begin{figure}\centering{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=5cm]{exampleimg}\caption{exampleimg}}\end{figure}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{mdframed}


\begin{mdframed}
\lipsum[4-6]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\label{milk-consumption-india}Asdkj sdlkj sldkjf lskjd flograms per capita per annum}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{lrrr}
Year & Rural & Urban & All\\
\hline
1983 & 38.7 & 55.6 & 44.7\\
1993–1994 & 50.3 & 66.4 & 54.3\\
2004–2005 & 50.2 & 69.3 & 55\\
2009–2010 & 51.7 & 71.6 & 57.1\\
\end{tabulary}
\end{center}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[] \footnotesize Source: \citet{anjani2014}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{mdframed}
```

How to insert a table or a figure inside `mdframed` box without making it float?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After clarifications from the OP through comments, it is better to use `\captionof` from `caption` package and get rid of both `figure` and `table` environments. For table notes, an extra row may be added as shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed,graphicx,caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mdframed}
      \lipsum[4]
      {\centering
      \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
      \captionof{figure}{exampleimg}
      \par}
      \lipsum[1]
\lipsum[4-6]
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{\label{milk-consumption-india}Asdkj sdlkj sldkjf lskjd flograms per capita per annum}
\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
  Year        & Rural & Urban & All   \\ \hline
  1983        & 38.7  & 55.6  & 44.7  \\
  1993–1994   & 50.3  & 66.4  & 54.3  \\
  2004–2005   & 50.2  & 69.3  & 55    \\
  2009–2010   & 51.7  & 71.6  & 57.1  \\
  \multicolumn{4}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize Source:} %\citet{anjani2014}}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1-3]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would one do this with a table? I am not able to add caption to a table. The caption takes the width of the table, and does not use the entire \textwidth. I just added the code I am using for inserting the table.

Comment: But my table does not have long content. I can do away of tabulary, if that helps.

Comment: puting mdframed inside \begin{table} and \end{table} creates all kinds of problems for me. pagebreaks stop working. Also, if a box has some text, a captioned table and a captioned figure, all hell breaks loose.

Comment: I have a text running over two and a half pages containing one figure and a table, that I would like to insert as a framed box in a document (manuscript for a book). Both figure and table have a caption.