# placing a figure within a user-defined environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, environments

I found a (I assume nice and simple) [way to add a vertical bar](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21077) beside a mathematical demonstration. I would like to be able to put a figure within this environment but I get the error: `./test.tex:21: LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.`

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\surroundwithmdframed[
   topline=false,
   rightline=false,
   bottomline=false,
   leftmargin=\parindent,
   skipabove=\medskipamount,
   skipbelow=\medskipamount
]{proof}

\begin{document}
   \noindent
   Preceding Text
   \begin{proof}[Proof by Paradox]

   my proof, I really wish a figure could be here\dots
   \end{proof}
   \dots but I can only compile if it is here:
   \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
        ...
        \caption{fig.1}
   \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I should add that the same error arises when attempting to place a figure within a user-defined environment using the `enviro` package.

Is there any way to place a figure within such environment ?

Comment: you had not to insert float in fixed environment. It can be included directly but than you need to use `\captionof{figure}{figure title}` from package `caption` or `capt-of` instead of `\caption{...}`.

Comment: The only reason to use `figure` rather than just `\includegraphics` is to allow latex to float it elsewhere to help with page breaking, you don't want this figure to float out of the environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mdframed box containing text captioned tables and figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232289/mdframed-box-containing-text-captioned-tables-and-figures)

Comment: @Alain, if you make own answer to your question, it should be published as answer, not a part of question. Now is less visible to other audience on site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it solved by comments.

Answer (score 2):

comments hinted the incompatibility between the figure environment and the user-defined environment, here is how it works:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}


\surroundwithmdframed[
   topline=false,
   rightline=false,
   bottomline=false,
   leftmargin=\parindent,
   skipabove=\medskipamount,
   skipbelow=\medskipamount
]{proof}

\begin{document}
   \noindent
   Preceding Text
   \begin{proof}[Proof]

   my proof, the related figure and\dots

   \begin{tikzpicture}[framed,background rectangle/.style={ultra thick,draw=none, top color=white, bottom color=white, rounded corners},scale=0.65]
        \begin{scope}[x={(.7cm,.3cm)},z={(.8cm,-.4cm)}]
        %
        % poutre
        \path (1,0,0);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\cylxx}{\cylxy}
        \path (0,1,0);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\cylyx}{\cylyy}
        \path (0,0,1);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\cylzx}{\cylzy}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cylt}{(\cylzy * \cylyx - \cylzx * \cylyy)/ (\cylzy * \cylxx - \cylzx * \cylxy)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ang}{atan(\cylt)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ct}{1/sqrt(1 + (\cylt)^2)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{\cylt * \ct}
        \fill[black!20] (\ct,\st,0) -- ++(0,0,-4) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=180,radius=1] -- ++(0,0,4) arc[start angle=\ang+180,delta angle=-180,radius=1];
        \begin{scope}[every path/.style={thick}]
        \draw[] (0,0,0) circle[radius=1];       
        \draw[] (\ct,\st,-4) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=180,radius=1];
        \draw[] (\ct,\st,-4) -- ++(0,0,4);
        \draw (-\ct,-\st,-4) -- ++(0,0,4);
        %
        %
        \draw[black!25,dashed] (\ct,\st,-8) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=180,radius=1];
        \draw[black!25,dashed] (\ct,\st,-8) arc[start angle=\ang,delta angle=-180,radius=1];
        \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{\dots its caption}


   \end{proof}
\end{document}
```