# Managing tabular within \mdframed environment

Tags: tables, floats, mdframed

I am working with the \mdframed environment to create boxes in a book. I need to insert tables or figures within the boxes, and I have the understanding that floats do not work very well within a frame. I did use tabular with \captionof, as suggested in this other thread:

[mdframed box containing text captioned tables and figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232289/mdframed-box-containing-text-captioned-tables-and-figures/352911#352911)

The problem is, nevertheless that the table can then be split between two pages. So I come back to my original questions. Is there a way to put a float (table or figure) within a \mdframed environment? And if not, how can I make sure that tables do not split over pages?

Thank you for your answers!!

Francesco

Comment: You put `mdframed` *inside* `table` or `figure`, not the other way around.

Comment: Did you try nesting `mdframed` in `table`, and not the converse?

Comment: @egreg: I was faster by 2 s!!!

Comment: Assuming that your frame contains more than only the table: Put a minipage around the tabular and the captionof if you want to keep them together.

Comment: Thanks to all! Just a question for the first solution: does the mdframed within the table constrain me to less than a page? I will try both solutions, thanks again