# How to put a figure created by TikZ + standalone inside an example default frame created by mdframed?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed, standalone

Got an error when tried to put a figure created by TikZ + `standalone` inside an `exampledefault` frame created by `mdframed`.

Below is the main code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{linewidth=2pt}
\newtheorem{my_definition}{DEFINITION}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[style=exampledefault]
\begin{my_definition}\textbf{[My Definition]:}\label{mine}
Let us see the figure below:

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
\includestandalone[width=.5\textwidth]{simple_figure}
\caption{Line description.}
\label{my_fig}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{my_definition}
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

And below is the figure code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [line width=1](-2.5,-2) rectangle (2.5,2) (2.5,2) node [above] {$U$};
\draw [line width=1] (-.5,0) circle (1) (-.5,1) node [above] {$A$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And finally below is the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16 \begin{figure}[h!]
                       
?
```

Comment: It doesn't have anything to with either TikZ or standalone I think, but the fact that you're putting a float (`figure`) in an `mdframed` environment. Try removing the `figure` environment, load the `capt-of` package, and use `\captionof{figure}{...}` instead of `\caption{...}`, as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/232290/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by question comments.

Comment: @Aria If you are interested, `tcolorbox` allow to have framed floating figures.